# App crashes after displaying nserror message in uialertview from parseErrorOccurred

Tags: ios, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, nsxmlparser, parse-error

I'm trying to post userid and password and retrieve user information using `HttpRequest`. I'm getting expected result, but client had reported the app is crashing after authentication. He had sent a video which shows how the app crashes. From that i concluded the app is crashing after displaying `nserror` message in uialertview from

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
```

The error message i'm getting is "The operation couldn't be completed. (`NSXMLParserErrorDomain` error `39`.)"

After showing this message in alert view the app is crashing suddenly. I'm not facing this crash anyhow. Can anyone help me to sort out this. Thanks in advance.

The code i have used in `parseErrorOccured` is

```
NSString *errorMessage = [error localizedDescription];
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Error!" message:errorMessage
                                                   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"   otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
[alertView release];
```

Comment: ask ur client to give a Crash log out of iTunes...do not speculate

Comment: Put this **NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);** , let us know the log.?

Comment: @KumarKl , the app is with the Client :) so NSLog unlikely

Comment: the log message in displayed in alert view..     The operation couldn't be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 39.)

Comment: Sometimes The **Error** may lead to app Crash, If we R trying to interact with it... May be for **NULL** ..

Comment: Ishank thanks for your comment.. i will ask the client for crash log..

Answer (score 0):

From experience, [error localizedDescription] or [error localizedFailureReason] may return a nil NSString.

In your code, you should check to see if errorMessage is nil, if it is try setting errorMessage to [error localizedFailureReason]. I'd check for a NULL value again.